# ListView Custom Adapter not adding all values from Loop for()

Tags: android, json, list, loops, view

Good Day guys, I'm having json array like this

```
{"id":"1114","user_id":"60","paq_type":"Electronics","description":"Karen Brso","title":"xvxcv","notes":"sdf","price":"410.00","size_x":"234","size_y":"234","size_z":"23","weight":"23","start_date":"2015-04-14","end_date":"2015-04-22","from_country":"Armenia","from_state":"Yerevan","from_city":"Yerevan","from_street":"7 Paronian d\/st","from_apt":"","from_longitute":"44.50389862060547","from_latitude":"40.17966024053021","to_country":"Armenia","to_state":"Yerevan","to_city":"Yerevan","to_street":"Antarain Street","to_apt":"","to_longitude":"44.511966705322266","to_latitude":"40.19395447720183","creator_first_name":"Miqo","creator_last_name":"Dallaqyan","creator_phone":"12345677","creator_email":"c","creator_file":"storage\/user\/60\/Penguins-2015-04-11-19-40-15.jpg","status":"1","candidates":null,"files":[{"file_path":"storage\/paq\/1114\/1428681680Koala.jpg","file_id":"235"}]},{"id":"1115","user_id":"60","paq_type":"Books","description":"kyk","title":"yuky","notes":"ykyk","price":"757.00","size_x":"6464","size_y":"646","size_z":"64","weight":"46","start_date":"2015-04-11","end_date":"2015-04-18","from_country":"Armenia","from_state":"Yerevan","from_city":"Yerevan","from_street":"Yeghvard Highway","from_apt":"","from_longitute":"44.50334072113037","from_latitude":"40.22662974852171","to_country":"Armenia","to_state":"Yerevan","to_city":"Yerevan","to_street":"9th Street","to_apt":"","to_longitude":"44.49767589569092","to_latitude":"40.2177168941058","creator_first_name":"Miqo","creator_last_name":"Dallaqyan","creator_phone":"12345677","creator_email":"c","creator_file":"storage\/user\/60\/Penguins-2015-04-11-19-40-15.jpg","status":"1","candidates":null,"files":null},{"id":"1116","user_id":"60","paq_type":"Books","description":"sdfgs","title":"ergdrfg","notes":"dfgdsfg","price":"330.00","size_x":"4532","size_y":"5344","size_z":"534","weight":"3","start_date":"2015-04-10","end_date":"2015-04-12","from_country":"Armenia","from_state":"Yerevan","from_city":"Yerevan","from_street":"1st line of the Aygedzor Street","from_apt":"","from_longitute":"44.50192451477051","from_latitude":"40.189758316404536","to_country":"Armenia","to_state":"Yerevan","to_city":"Yerevan","to_street":"7 Khanjyan Street","to_apt":"","to_longitude":"44.51617240905762","to_latitude":"40.17421714768112","creator_first_name":"Miqo","creator_last_name":"Dallaqyan","creator_phone":"12345677","creator_email":"c","creator_file":"storage\/user\/60\/Penguins-2015-04-11-19-40-15.jpg","status":"1","candidates":null,"files":null},{"id":"1117","user_id":"60","paq_type":"Books","description":"sdfgs","title":"ergdrfg","notes":"dfgdsfg","price":"330.00","size_x":"4532","size_y":"5344","size_z":"534","weight":"3","start_date":"2015-04-11","end_date":"2015-04-13","from_country":"Armenia","from_state":"Yerevan","from_city":"Yerevan","from_street":"1st line of the Aygedzor Street","from_apt":"","from_longitute":"44.50192451477051","from_latitude":"40.189758316404536","to_country":"Armenia","to_state":"Yerevan","to_city":"Yerevan","to_street":"7 Khanjyan Street","to_apt":"","to_longitude":"44.51617240905762","to_latitude":"40.17421714768112","creator_first_name":"Miqo","creator_last_name":"Dallaqyan","creator_phone":"12345677","creator_email":"c","creator_file":"storage\/user\/60\/Penguins-2015-04-11-19-40-15.jpg","status":"1","candidates":null,"files":null},{"id":"1118","user_id":"60","paq_type":"Books","description":"ghdf","title":"dghdf","notes":"ghdfgh","price":"150.00","size_x":"4532","size_y":"123","size_z":"1423","weight":"231","start_date":"2015-04-11","end_date":"2015-04-22","from_country":"Armenia","from_state":"Yerevan","from_city":"Yerevan","from_street":"Vahagn Davtyan Street","from_apt":"","from_longitute":"44.51119422912598","from_latitude":"40.20096935364624","to_country":"Armenia","to_state":"Yerevan","to_city":"Yerevan","to_street":"Simeon Yerevantsi Street","to_apt":"","to_longitude":"44.50037956237793","to_latitude":"40.18202096431908","creator_first_name":"Miqo","creator_last_name":"Dallaqyan","creator_phone":"12345677
05-13 11:27:12.744  14750-14898/com.paqqy D/anasun﹕ [{"id":"1194","user_id":"61","paq_type":"Electronics","description":"werdszfsdf","title":"werwer","notes":"werwer","price":"420.00","size_x":"2","size_y":"23","size_z":"3","weight":"3","start_date":"2015-04-23","end_date":"2015-04-30","from_country":"Armenia","from_state":"Yerevan","from_city":"Yerevan","from_street":"Michurin Street","from_apt":"","from_longitute":"44.489994049072266","from_latitude":"40.14893055361652","to_country":"Armenia","to_state":"Yerevan","to_city":"Yerevan","to_street":"12 9 of May Street","to_apt":"","to_longitude":"44.503211975097656","to_latitude":"40.15916439538877","creator_first_name":"Hovsep","creator_last_name":"Markosyan","creator_phone":"077310128","creator_email":"markosyanhoso@mail.ru","creator_file":"storage\/user\/61\/Lighthouse-2015-04-12-00-57-14.jpg","status":"1","candidates":null,"files":[{"file_path":"storage\/paq\/1194\/1428700691Tulips.jpg","file_id":"242"}]},{"id":"1203","user_id":"61","paq_type":"Books","description":"sdfsfasdasdh","title":"iPhone","notes":"ik","price":"200.00","size_x":"44","size_y":"22","size_z":"88","weight":"99","start_date":"2015-04-25","end_date":"2015-04-27","from_country":"Armenia","from_state":"Yerevan","from_city":"Yerevan","from_street":"8 Garegin Nzhdeh Street","from_apt":"","from_longitute":"44.486622512340546","from_latitude":"40.15115498733384","to_country":"Armenia","to_state":"Yerevan","to_city":"Yerevan","to_street":"6 Garegin Nzhdeh Street","to_apt":"","to_longitude":"44.48618799448013","to_latitude":"40.15090897059796","creator_first_name":"Hovsep","creator_last_name":"Markosyan","creator_phone":"077310128","creator_email":"markosyanhoso@mail.ru","creator_file":"storage\/user\/61\/Lighthouse-2015-04-12-00-57-14.jpg","status":"1","candidates":null,"files":[{"file_path":"storage\/paq\/1203\/142894802212182_small_550 - Copy (2).jpg","file_id":"275"}]}]
```

Im parsing this json and giving it to loop like this.

```
public void addpaqs() {
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(paqsresponse);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
            tolongitude = row.getString("to_longitude");
            tolatitude = row.getString("to_latitude");
            creatorfirstname = row.getString("creator_first_name");
            creatorlastname = row.getString("creator_last_name");
            paqtype = row.getString("paq_type");
            startdate = row.getString("start_date");
            enddate = row.getString("end_date");
            fromplace = row.getString("from_country");
            toplace = row.getString("to_country");
            fromcity = row.getString("from_city");
            tocity = row.getString("to_city");
            String price = row.getString("price");
            fromlatitude = row.getString("from_latitude");
            fromlongitude = row.getString("from_longitute");
            tolatitude = row.getString("to_latitude");
            tolongitude = row.getString("to_longitude");
            Log.d("fromplace", fromplace);
            double tolongdouble = Double.parseDouble(tolongitude);
            double tolatdouble = Double.parseDouble(tolatitude);
            Paqs paqs = new Paqs(R.drawable.cross,R.drawable.accountimage, creatorfirstname+creatorlastname,price, paqtype,startdate+"/"+enddate,fromplace+fromcity,toplace+tocity);
            paqsarray.add(paqs);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I created custom adapter to be able to put all my info from this `JSON` into `ListView` and here is my custom adapter class;

```
package com.paqqy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    protected List<Paqs> listCars;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Paqs> listCars) {
        this.listCars = listCars;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listCars.size();
    }

    public Paqs getItem(int position) {
        return listCars.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return listCars.get(position).getDrawableId();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item,
                    parent, false);

            holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_name_id);
            holder.paqtype = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_paq_id);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_price_id);
            holder.date= (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_date_id);
            holder.from= (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_from_id);
            holder.to= (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_to_id);
            holder.imgCar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_general_id);
            holder.paqsimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_paq_general_id);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Paqs paqs = listCars.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(paqs.getFirstname());
        holder.paqtype.setText(paqs.getPaqtype());
        holder.date.setText(paqs.getDate());
        holder.from.setText(paqs.getFrom());
        holder.to.setText(paqs.getTo());
        holder.txtPrice.setText(" $" + paqs.getPrice());
        holder.imgCar.setImageResource(paqs.getDrawableId());
        holder.paqsimage.setImageResource(paqs.getPaqsimage());
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView paqtype;
        TextView date;
        TextView from;
        TextView to;
        TextView txtPrice;
        ImageView imgCar;
        ImageView paqsimage;
    }

}
```

And here is Paqs.class file from where my adapter gets the list

```
    package com.paqqy;
    public class Paqs {

    private int drawableId;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String price;
    private String paqtype;
    private String date;
    private String from,to;
    private int paqsimage;

    public Paqs(int drawableId,int paqsimage, String firstname, String price,String paqtype,String date,String from,String to) {
        super();
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
        this.paqsimage = paqsimage;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.price = price;
        this.paqtype = paqtype;
        this.date = date;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from){
        this.from = from;
    }
    public void setTo(String to){
        this.to = to;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public void setPaqtype(String paqtype) {
        this.paqtype = paqtype;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
public  String getFrom(){
    return from;
}
    public String getTo(){
        return to;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public String getPaqtype() {
        return paqtype;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }

    public int getDrawableId() {
        return drawableId;
    }

    public void setDrawableId(int drawableId) {
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
    public int getPaqsimage() {
        return paqsimage;
    }

    public void setPaqsimage(int paqsimage) {
        this.paqsimage = paqsimage;
    }

}
```

The problem is that after loop I only see 2 values inside `ListView`,and nothing more.. but in my `JSON` I have heaps of values as you can see,so did I do something wrong in my loop? I don't know and have no clue what is the proble.Thanks beforehand!

Comment: not valit json.Check out http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

So, there is one thing that could happened, sorry, i dnot' really want to read all your json, i'm just making a guess  `tolongitude = row.getString("to_longitude");` this line can throw an exception, as all lines for getting values in your code, so, if there is no string with that name in one of the objects, he will not added. **Solution** : `use object.optString(name)`, just add `opt` to all your getting methods, this should work, post me i ncomment if it helps

Comment: man i just forgot it got dammit your wonderfull,checking right now is it like that or no!:) and what an idiot gave -1?pricks!

Comment: not worked...:( i removed all lines for long and lat as at this point i dont need,and checked rest,and i do receive rest but still its same....